# YouTube API Resumable Uploader Session Token

Tags: wpf, authentication, upload, youtube-api

I am working with the YouTube api trying to upload a video using the resumable uploader. I would really rather not have to directly ask the user for their credentials.

I am able to use AuthSub and get a session token. The problem is I cant seem to use this with the resumable uploader. Is this possible or is this totally separate? I see that GDataCredentials can take a client token. What is this? I i use the session token I get back Error = {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}

Here is my code

```
Video newVideo;

var mResumableUploader = new ResumableUploader(10485760);
mResumableUploader.AsyncOperationCompleted += mResumableUploader_AsyncOperationCompleted;
mResumableUploader.AsyncOperationProgress += mResumableUploader_AsyncOperationProgress;

var youTubeAuthenticator = new ClientLoginAuthenticator(AppName, ServiceNames.YouTube, new GDataCredentials(YouTubeToken));
youTubeAuthenticator.DeveloperKey = DevKey;

newVideo = new Video();

newVideo.Title = "video";
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Entertainment", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.Keywords = "video";
newVideo.Description = "video";
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(FilePath, "video/mp4");

var link = new AtomLink("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads");
link.Rel = ResumableUploader.CreateMediaRelation;
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Links.Add(link);

mResumableUploader.InsertAsync(youTubeAuthenticator, newVideo.YouTubeEntry, "inserter");
```

Answer (score 0):

[ClientLogin is problematic](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/03/clientlogin-fail.html) and will be deprecated soon. Please use [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) and you won't have problems.